# TransactionScope - IEnlistmentNotification

Tags: c#, transactionscope

If create a custom of IEnlistmentNotification is it possible to make it the first implementation executed when TransactionScope.Commit is called?

Comment: any final solution with full source code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your enlistment depends on the order commit notifications occur, you're doing it wrong.